# jQuery update slider's value on text field change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a rails project that updates the slider's value to that of the text-field on **any-change** (probably *keydown* or change event).

My `_form.html.erb` file:

```
<div id="my-slider" class="slider-input"></div>
<%= f.input :var_name, label: false, wrapper: :append do %>
<%= f.text_field :var_name, value: @controller_name.var_name,
    id: "var_name", class: 'my-border answer-single', data: {autonumeric: true, aPad: false} %>
```

And the js code for the `keydown` event for `my-input` element is this:

```
$("#var_name").keydown(function(){
    alert("hey");
    var value = this.value();
    $("#my-slider").slider('value', value);
});
```

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/MD3mX/1127/) is a JSFiddle that displays **only the alert** with the `keydown` or `change` events, but doesn't change the slider.

The problem is that at my application, I only have an alert into the jQuery selector and it **doesn't display even the alert**.

Answer (score 1):

***DEMO ->*** http://jsfiddle.net/MD3mX/1132/

Use `keyup` instead of `change`.

Also use `this.value` instead of `this.value()` .. No parentheses required

```
$("#my-input").keyup(function () {
    $("#slider").slider("value", this.value);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help regarding the JSFiddle. But what about the problem with my rails app, that doesn't even display the alert? Its code is the one posted above (not the JSFiddle).

Comment: @Chris Is your javascript code wrapped in the jquery.ready() function?

Comment: @Brett: No Brett, it as it is posted above (Excuse my ignorance, I am new to this kind of stuff).

Comment: Try putting that code inside the document ready function, like this: 
`$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#my-input").keyup(function () {
  $("#slider").slider("value", this.value);
 });
});`

Comment: @Brett: Adding, created problems with some other buttons of the application. :/

Comment: @Kristna How can we make code not to run, if a number is belong a defined number. say like 500?

Comment: @Nofel - wrap everything inside the function using this `if(this.value == "500") {}`

Comment: @Nofel - http://jsfiddle.net/MD3mX/1434/ Take a peek at this. the slider won't change only when you enter 50.

Comment: @Krishna don't know if this is right thread to comment, but [my code] change when i even put 5, whereas i don't want it to execute any code in change function unless, the value is of min (http://jsfiddle.net/vLu6ytm8/)